# Disable priority inbox function and send all email to inbox

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

I have tried unsubscribing the "Important" folder and hiding it in Gmail.  Now I have succeeded in hiding the folder but email is still added there by the Gmail Priority Inbox "feature".  Can I disable this feature so I can read mail and manage it myself from one folder, preferably the Inbox?

Answer (score 2):

The use of the priority inbox is controlled by the settings:

To turn it off:

1. go to : gear, settings.
2. Click on the inbox tab.
3. Change inbox to default.
4. click save changes.

Note: I also have don't use markers/don't use my past actions/don't override filters selected.